# Viewing just the lighting effects without the object

Tags: geometry-nodes, compositing-nodes, lighting

Viewing just the lighting effects without the object.

Example:
I have a scene created with geometry nodes which an object (the sphere) creates an animated lighting effect (see below).  **How can I keep the animated lighting effects but not have the sphere be visible in the scene**.

Please note I will be testing different shapes and combination of shapes to see what interesting effects are created I just don't want to have the object/objects be visible in the scene.  Ideally it would be nice to do this in EEVEE to see the effects in "real-time" but whatever works is ok with me.

[image: ani1]

I tried disabling these options but lighting or object disappeared EEVEE.

[image: img1]

Using Cycles:

[image: img2]

Everything goes dark.  And the object can still be scene.
I'm trying to keep the lighting effects but hide the object.

[image: img3]

See attached file below.

[image]

Ps: I'm using Blender 3.5.1

Comment: In object properties you can disable its camera ray visibility

Comment: @AllenSimpson I added another image showing what I tried to disable.  I didn't see that option.

Comment: Oh, huh, I didn't expect it to eliminate the emission rays as well!  Will have to do some testing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess maybe you disabled Camera on the wrong object.

[image]

You can disable Camera rays on the emissive object (the cube in my scene) and the light emission is still visible on the plane below, even what would normally be occluded by the object.

Comment: Thanks the issue was I created both the walls and Object within the same geometry node.  Once I placed the wall section in it's own geometry node section it worked like a charm.  Thanks!